# RxSwift equivalent BehaviorSubject's .modify() method

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

Reactive BehaviorSubject has a modify method while exposes the values as inout and allows you to modify them. Any RxSwift property that allows similar behaviour?

Comment: Any reference of `BehaviorSubject.modify` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any property that allows this, but you could write your own extension for this.

```swift
extension BehaviorRelay {
    var inoutValue: Element {
        get { return value }
        set { accept(newValue) }
    }
}

// for example
extension BehaviorRelay where Element == Int {
    func increment() {
        inoutValue += 1
    }
}
```